# ASP.NET MVC (SharePoint PHA) file save doesn't work in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, download

My MVC app accepts an excel file and uses that file to create list items in SharePoint. This works in all non-IE browsers (including Opera..).  My code starts as follows:

```
public ActionResult ParseExcel() //RedirectResult
        {
            try
            {

                if (Request.Files.Count == 1)
                {
                    var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);

                    using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
                    {
                        if (clientContext != null)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                if (Request.Files[0].FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
                                {
                                    //1. Temporarily store Excel file for processing
                                    string folder = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "HNZ");
                                    if (!Directory.Exists(folder)) Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
                                    string localExcelPath = Path.Combine(folder, Request.Files[0].FileName);
                                    Request.Files[0].SaveAs(localExcelPath);
```

I'm 99% sure that the failure happens at this point, as no progress to the rest of the code happens. I didn't have this issue in my development environment, and unfortunately I can't actually debug the issue in pre-prod.

Update:  From what I've read, I can add something like             `HttpContext.Response.CacheControl = Request.Browser.Browser == "IE" ? "private" : "no-cache"` to my code in order to account for IE. Is this really all there is to it? If so, is there somewhere particular I need to add this or should it not matter as long as it happens before the "Save" ? I'm going to try to set a bounty on this question if I'm able to before the project has to be scrapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this may be an issue with the "SaveAs" method because IE seems to be storing `localExcelPath` as a full path ("MyFolder/Blah/Test.xlsx") in my prod environment where all the other browsers I've used are storing it as "Test.xlsx." This didn't happen in my test environment as there was no server involved.

edit: This was the issue.